# Removing one strip of LEDs from panel

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver, repair, diy

My LED panel broke (it is a ceiling lamp).
I disassembled it, and it looks like this:

[image: LED panel]

It has a series of LED strips (the last one is missing in the image), connected in series. There are connectors like the one on the left in the picture between strips; the last connector is just a closed loop of wire, and the first strip is attached to the transformer:

[image]

By testing individual strips, I discovered that one of them is broken (some of its LEDs look damaged, with a black dot in the center). With all the strips, the panel doesn't work when attached to AC.

I'd like to repair it, I'd be fine with one less strip (since I can't find a replacement online).

**Questions:**

1. If I remove the broken strip, should I expect the others to break? I'm confused by what I read on the transformer label, it says "Output: 30-39V". Why is there a delta? Is the transformer/driver able to regulate the voltage/current depending on what is connected to it?
2. If the answer to 1 is "yes", is there something I can do to avoid it?
3. Bonus question: as you may see in the first image, there are arrows on the strips, reading "+/-" on the right, and "+/+" on the left. They were mounted like this:

→
←  this one failed
←
←
←
TRANSFORMER

I this it doesn't make sense, I would have expected either all the same direction, or alternating ones. Does it make a difference?

I apologize for my scarce knowledge of electronics if the question is trivial, my local repair shop did not even want to see the LEDs and I wanted to try some DIY.

Thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to say anything. In a broad way, I'm afraid that this site is not fitted for this kind of DIY repair question. Surely this panel can be fixed, but, find the best ways of doing this repair need some "mileage", and it would be irresponsible to direct you to a path that could increase your problems. By now, what you have is just a LED panel that doesn't light up; I'm sure that this is far better than an incorrectly fixed panel that will provides you with a real fire hazard.

Comment: **Probably** this power source has a fixed current output, if so, the fix would make a bypass to eliminate the burnt LED, or the section where it is installed - but this is the kind of solution that should be done only after measuring carefully voltage and current in several points of the circuit, with a multimeter. Another, and safer, option would be to try to identify and replace only the burnt led.

Comment: What would really permit someone to be able to help you would be if you provided a drawing showing the way that all the strips, and also all the LEDs inside each strips, are wired one to the others and to the power source. But, I repeat, this would not be a question well fitted for EE.StackExchange.

Comment: @mguima It says CC and 1150 mA and the Vf range.

Comment: @winny Yes, I saw the photo of the supply. But there were a lot of times when I got somewhat scolded by the multi-thousand-rep-pundits of EE.SE, just because I said to an OP something that was not a "safety first" answer. So, even if OP provided a photo of the supply, I still think that will not be safe to guide an unexperienced OP to fix this device without a good understanding of the whole circuit. After all, can we really trust what is said in the label of a device that we can't put our hands and our multimeter probes on?

Comment: @mguima Thank you for the comments. I like the "safety first" approach and by no means I want to bypass my incompetence (for instance, I do have a multimeter, but I would not feel comfortable using it on anything connected to AC). I thought this might be a situation in which it would be super-safe, super-easy to say either "yeah try without a strip", or "you need a resistor if you have fewer LEDs", or "throw the whole thing away".
If we're in a "it depends" kind of situation, I'm more than happy to go with option 3 and not risk it :)

Comment: I think I'll just buy a [set of new replacement LEDs](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41fLuemibZL._AC_SX466_.jpg) which come with their own transformer/controller, this way I can still reuse the panel exterior.

Comment: @mguima I would also accept the resolution as an answer if you want to post it

Comment: if you want to proceed with troubleshooting, then start by drawing a schematic diagram of one LED strip .... confirm that all of the strips are identical .... next determine how the strips are interconnected electrically (overall schematic diagram) ... do not forget to include any device that may be connected at the end of the LED strip chain .... when you have that info, determine what would be the effect of shorting out one of the LEDs ... if the effect would not be catastrophic, then use a DMM to measure the current through the point where the burned LED is located

Comment: The question is just that. In my opinion, this is the kind of repair that could be easily done, but, not by any person. It's perfectly possible and safe to use a multimeter to probe this device even connected to AC, BUT, this measure has to be done by a person with proper knowledge and experience. If you have the sincerity to admit that you are afraid of using a multimeter in such a device, **this is not a fault or yours**: no, I praise you for admitting that. But, the other side is that is not adviseable that you try to repair it by yourself.

Comment: A safer approach would be this: take a low voltage source (5 V to 12V), connect it to a resistor, and try to probe each individual LED in the failed strip. If you can isolate **just the one LED** that is burnt, you could try to replace it.